# Выборка элементов опредленного типа по условию

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sql

Задача следующая. У меня есть таблица с товарами. У пользователя есть возможность выбрать приоритетное направление товаров (к примеру, молочные продукты). Заходя на сайт я должен отображать пользователю один из товаров соответствующего направления. Не должно быть такого, что какой-то товар был показан значительно больше раз, а другой не показан вообще. Как реализовать подобное?

PS Пока идея такая. Добавить дополнительную табличку (товар, счетчик показов). В нее мы записываем сколько раз какой товар отображали.  При получении запроса на объект, запрашиваю элементы из главной таблички, иду по вспомогательной. Если элемент не найден, добавляю, если есть лишний выкидываю. Затем смотрю, у кого самый маленький счетчик, извлекаю этот элемент, обновляю счетчик, отображаю элемент.

Получается очень массивно. Есть ли более простое решение?

Comment: Хм ну зачем так запутано.. Можно через галерею на jq и выглядеть будет супер. Много скриптов на сайте евгения попова на эту тему.

Comment: Можно проходить в цикле, скажем, в порядке возрастания ID. И хранить ID последнего показанного.

Comment: @LordyGL, Если не затруднит поясните, что за **jq** (если JQuery, то не ясно причем тут это)?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

1. дополнительная таблица, в которой только одно поле id, которое является foreign key на id вашего товара;
2. выбираем в случайном порядке из товаров все товары, у которых нету записи в дополнительной таблице (результат выборки ограничиваем необходимым количеством);
3. если количество записей в дополнительной таблице + количество выбраных товаров = количество записей в таблице товаров, удаляем все записи из дополнительной таблицы; в противном случае добавляем в дополнительную таблицу id только что выбранного товара (или товаров в зависимости от необходимой логики).